# Unable to connect and retrieve files from SFTP host using Spring Integration 6.1.0 Java DSL

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration-sftp

I am trying to follow the example mentioned here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#configuring-with-the-java-dsl

but unable to make it work. some of the errors I am seeing in the logs are `failed to create SFTP Session`, `Failed to obtain pooled item`, `Failed to execute on session` etc.

Note: I am able to connect to the host using file-zila/terminal with the same user and password without any issues. Also JSch library works just fine.

This looks to be a very basic sample code not sure what am I missing here. Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated !!

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow sftpInboundFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow
                .from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(this.sftpSessionFactory())
                                .preserveTimestamp(true)
                                .remoteDirectory("/")
                                .regexFilter(".*\\.txt$")
                                .localFilenameExpression("#this.toUpperCase() + '.a'")
                                .localDirectory(new File("sftp-inbound")),
                        e -> e.id("sftpInboundAdapter")
                                .autoStartup(true)
                                .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000)))
                .handle(m -> System.out.println(m.getPayload()))
                .get();
    }

@Bean
    public SessionFactory<SftpClient.DirEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        factory.setHost("XXXXXXXX");
        factory.setPort(22);
        factory.setUser("XXXXXXX");
        factory.setPassword("XXXXXXXXX");
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);        
        return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
    }
```

below is the error log -

```
2023-05-31T03:43:14.771+05:30 ERROR 87833 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing '/' to local directory
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:348)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:267)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:69)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractFetchLimitingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractFetchLimitingMessageSource.java:47)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:443)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:412)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:348)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$5(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:341)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:96)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:461)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:341)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.util.PoolItemNotAvailableException: Failed to obtain pooled item
    at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:196)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory.getSession(CachingSessionFactory.java:134)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:447)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:68)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:85)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:82)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.doGetItem(SimplePool.java:206)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:187)
    ... 23 more
```